# Gradle MessageIOException on jmsConnectionFactory.createContext of IBM MQ

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, integration-testing, ibm-mq

I encountered a strange problem with my multi-module Spring project.

One module provides a service to connect with an IBM MQ:

```
// imports 

@Service
@NoArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class MessageQueueService {

    @Autowired
    protected MqAdapterConfig messageQueueConfig;

    @Override
    public void produce(final Message message) throws MessageQueueServiceException {
        log.info("Producing a Message...");
        try (JMSContext jmsContext = initJmsContext()) {
            produce(jmsContext, message);
        }
    }

    private void produce(JMSContext jmsContext, Message message) throws MessageQueueServiceException {
        // send message
    }

    private JMSContext initJmsContext() throws MessageQueueServiceException {

        try {
            System.setProperty(messageQueueConfig.getCipher().getOrDefault(
                            MqAdapterIbmMqConfig.MQ_CIPHER_MAPPINGS_IBM_PROPERTY,
                            "com.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings"),
                    messageQueueConfig.getCipher().getOrDefault(
                            MqAdapterIbmMqConfig.MQ_CIPHER_MAPPINGS_IBM_VALUE, "false"));

            var jmsFactoryFactory = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(JmsConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
            var jmsConnectionFactory = jmsFactoryFactory.createConnectionFactory();

            configureConnectionFactory(jmsConnectionFactory);

            JMSContext jmsContext = jmsConnectionFactory.createContext(JMSContext.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            log.debug("JMSContext: {}", jmsContext);

            return jmsContext;
        } catch (JMSException | UnrecoverableKeyException | KeyManagementException | KeyStoreException
                 | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException | IOException | NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new MessageQueueServiceException("consume() - Error.", e);
        }


    }

    private void configureConnectionFactory(final JmsConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory) throws JMSException,
            KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyManagementException, IOException,
            CertificateException, NumberFormatException {

        // configureConnectionFactory
        var sslSocketFactory = createSSLSocketFactory(messageQueueConfig);
        if (sslSocketFactory != null) {
            jmsConnectionFactory.setObjectProperty(CommonConstants.WMQ_SSL_SOCKET_FACTORY, sslSocketFactory);
        }

        // connectionNameList
        String host1 = messageQueueConfig.getServer().getOrDefault(MqAdapterIbmMqConfig.MQ_SERVER_1_URL,
                "0.0.0.0");
        String host2 = messageQueueConfig.getServer().getOrDefault(MqAdapterIbmMqConfig.MQ_SERVER_2_URL,
                "0.0.0.0");
        String port1 = messageQueueConfig.getServer().getOrDefault(MqAdapterIbmMqConfig.MQ_SERVER_1_PORT, "-1");
        String port2 = messageQueueConfig.getServer().getOrDefault(MqAdapterIbmMqConfig.MQ_SERVER_2_PORT, "-1");
        String connectionNameList = String.format("%s(%s),%s(%s)", host1, port1, host2, port2);
        jmsConnectionFactory.setStringProperty(CommonConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_NAME_LIST, connectionNameList);

        jmsConnectionFactory.setStringProperty(CommonConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL,
                messageQueueConfig.getChannel().getOrDefault(MqAdapterIbmMqConfig.MQ_CHANNEL_1, ""));
        jmsConnectionFactory.setIntProperty(CommonConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, CommonConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
        jmsConnectionFactory.setStringProperty(CommonConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER,
                messageQueueConfig.getQueue().getOrDefault(MqAdapterIbmMqConfig.MQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, ""));
        jmsConnectionFactory.setStringProperty(CommonConstants.WMQ_APPLICATIONNAME, appName);
        jmsConnectionFactory.setBooleanProperty(JmsConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP, true);
        jmsConnectionFactory.setStringProperty(JmsConstants.USERID,
                messageQueueConfig.getUser().getOrDefault(MqAdapterIbmMqConfig.MQ_USER_2_NAME, ""));
        jmsConnectionFactory.setStringProperty(JmsConstants.PASSWORD,
                messageQueueConfig.getUser().getOrDefault(MqAdapterIbmMqConfig.MQ_USER_2_PWD, ""));
        var cipherSuite = messageQueueConfig.getCipher().getOrDefault(MqAdapterIbmMqConfig.MQ_CIPHER_SUITE_1, "");
        if (!cipherSuite.equals("")) {
            jmsConnectionFactory.setStringProperty(CommonConstants.WMQ_SSL_CIPHER_SUITE, cipherSuite);
        }
    }

    private SSLSocketFactory createSSLSocketFactory(final MqAdapterIbmMqConfig messageQueueConfig)
            throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyManagementException,
            IOException, CertificateException {

        var keystoreInstance = messageQueueConfig.getSecurity()
                .getOrDefault(MqAdapterIbmMqConfig.MQ_SECURITY_KEYSTORE_INSTANCE, "");
        if (keystoreInstance.equals("")) {
            return null;
        }

        final KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keystoreInstance);
        final FileInputStream keyStoreInputStream = new FileInputStream(messageQueueConfig.getSecurity()
                .getOrDefault(MqAdapterIbmMqConfig.MQ_SECURITY_KEYSTORE_NAME, ""));
        keyStore.load(keyStoreInputStream, messageQueueConfig.getSecurity()
                .getOrDefault(MqAdapterIbmMqConfig.MQ_SECURITY_KEYSTORE_PWD, "").toCharArray());

        final KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keystoreInstance);
        final FileInputStream trustStoreInputStream = new FileInputStream(messageQueueConfig.getSecurity()
                .getOrDefault(MqAdapterIbmMqConfig.MQ_SECURITY_TRUSTSTORE_NAME, ""));
        trustStore.load(trustStoreInputStream, messageQueueConfig.getSecurity()
                .getOrDefault(MqAdapterIbmMqConfig.MQ_SECURITY_TRUSTSTORE_PWD, "").toCharArray());

        keyStoreInputStream.close();
        trustStoreInputStream.close();

        final KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory
                .getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        final TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory
                .getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());

        keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, messageQueueConfig.getSecurity()
                .getOrDefault(MqAdapterIbmMqConfig.MQ_SECURITY_KEYSTORE_PWD, "").toCharArray());
        trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);

        final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance(
                messageQueueConfig.getSecurity().getOrDefault(MqAdapterIbmMqConfig.MQ_SSL_CONTEXT, ""));
        sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);

        return sslContext.getSocketFactory();
    }

}
```

So basically, it creates (or should create) a JMSContext with the config provided in the autowired `messageQueueConfig`.

Now, in a separate modul, I'm writing integration tests which use separate test queues. Since my test queues don't require keystores, the above service method is only setting the socket factory when a required keystore is present.
My test looks like that:

```
// imports

@SpringBootTest(classes = {MessageQueueService.class, MqAdapterConfig.class})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Testcontainers
@SpringJUnitConfig
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
        "adapter.mq.server.1.url=localhost",
        "adapter.mq.server.2.url=localhost",
        "adapter.mq.server.1.port=" + IbmMqIntegrationTest.CONTAINER_PORT,
        "adapter.mq.server.2.port=" + IbmMqIntegrationTest.CONTAINER_PORT,
        "adapter.mq.channel.1=STUB.CHANNEL",
        "adapter.mq.channel.2=STUB.CHANNEL",
        "adapter.mq.queue.manager=QMGR",
        "adapter.mq.queue.oneway=IBMMQ.ONE.WAY",
        "adapter.mq.queue.request=IBMMQ.REQUEST",
        "adapter.mq.queue.response=IBMMQ.REPLY",
        "adapter.mq.user.1.name=",
        "adapter.mq.user.1.pwd=",
        "adapter.mq.user.2.name=",
        "adapter.mq.user.2.pwd=",
        "adapter.mq.security.keystore.instance="
})
public class IbmMqIntegrationTest {

    public final static int CONTAINER_PORT = 59567;

    @Autowired
    private MessageQueueService ibmMqMessageQueueService;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void setUp() {
        // starting an IBM MQ Docker container on localhost:59567
    }

    @Test
    void testIbmMqConnection() throws MessageQueueServiceException {

        Message message = new Message();
        ibmMqMessageQueueService.produce(message);

    }

}
```

So all it does is overriding some config values for a special test Docker container queue, which gets then started, and a message is sent through the service. Now what happens is the following:

At `JMSContext jmsContext = jmsConnectionFactory.createContext(JMSContext.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);`, the test interrupts with an exception:

```
Unexpected exception thrown.
org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.MessageIOException: Could not read message from '/127.0.0.1:59886'.
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection.receive(SocketConnection.java:94)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$ConnectionReceive.run(MessageHub.java:270)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.InterHubMessageSerializer$MessageReader.read(InterHubMessageSerializer.java:72)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.InterHubMessageSerializer$MessageReader.read(InterHubMessageSerializer.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection.receive(SocketConnection.java:81)
    ... 6 more
```

... and I have no idea why. The port (59886 here) differs from run to run. It's a Gradle exception though, so here are my `build.gradle`s for both modules in case something's wrong there.

For the integration test module:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':mq-adapter-ibmmq')

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework:spring-jms:2.5'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine'
    testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:testcontainers:1.19.0'
    testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter:1.19.0'

    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-tx:3.1.2.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.openapitools:jackson-databind-nullable:0.2.6'
}

sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
        java.srcDir 'src/test/java'
        resources.srcDir 'src/test/resources'
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
        runtimeClasspath += output + compileClasspath
    }
}

configurations {
    integrationTestImplementation.extendsFrom testImplementation
    integrationTestRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom testRuntimeOnly
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
    classpath += sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
}

check.dependsOn integrationTest
```

For the service module:

```
plugins {
    id 'war'
    id 'base'
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir "${buildDir}/generated/src/main/java"
        }
        resources {
            srcDir "${buildDir}/generated/src/main/resources"
        }
    }
}

war {
    enabled = true
}

dependencies {
    api project(':mq-adapter-api')
    api project(':mq-adapter-common')

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-context'
    implementation 'io.swagger:swagger-annotations:1.6.11'
    implementation 'io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations:2.2.15'
    implementation 'javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final'
    implementation 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:4.0.1'
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.12'

    implementation (group: 'com.ibm.mq', name: 'com.ibm.mq.allclient', version: '9.2.2.0') {
        exclude (group: 'org.bouncycastle', module: 'bcprov-jdk15on')
        exclude (group: 'org.bouncycastle', module: 'bcpkix-jdk15on')
    }

    runtimeOnly 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.3.1'
    runtimeOnly 'com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:4.2.0'
}
```

and for completeness, the parent one of the whole project:

```
plugins {
    id 'jacoco'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' apply false
}

allprojects {
    group = 'my.group'
    version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    apply plugin: 'jacoco'

    ext {
        artifactoryRepo = version.contains("SNAPSHOT") ?
                project.property('upload.snapshot.repository.url') : project.property('upload.release.repository.url')
        println '**** version is ' + version + ' ****'
        println '**** artifactoryRepo is ' + artifactoryRepo + ' ****'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()

        maven {
            credentials {
                username project.property('nexus.user.name')
                password project.property('nexus.user.password')
            }
            url project.property('nexus.central.repository.url')
        }

        maven {
            credentials {
                username project.property('nexus.user.name')
                password project.property('nexus.user.password')
            }
            url project.property('nexus.fms-maven-mixed.repository.url')
        }

        maven {
            credentials {
                username System.getenv('$GIT_USER')
                password System.getenv('$GIT_PASSWORD')
            }
            url "${artifactoryRepo}"
        }

        maven {
            credentials {
                username System.getenv('$GIT_USER')
                password System.getenv('$GIT_PASSWORD')
            }
            url "${artifactoryRepo}"
        }
    }
}

subprojects {
    task allDeps(type: DependencyReportTask) {}

    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
    apply plugin: 'java-library'
    apply plugin: 'project-report'

    defaultTasks "build"

    java {
        toolchain {
            languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(11)
        }
        //withJavadocJar()
        withSourcesJar()
    }

    dependencyManagement {
        dependencies {
            dependencySet(group: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '2.7.5') {
                entry('spring-boot-starter-web') {
                    exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
                }
                entry('spring-boot-starter-actuator')
                entry('spring-boot-starter-security')
                entry('spring-boot-starter-test')
                entry('spring-boot-starter-validation')
            }
            dependencySet(group: 'org.springframework', version: '5.3.23') {
                entry('spring-context-support')
                entry('spring-context')
                entry('spring-web')
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        //lombok
        compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
        annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
        testImplementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
        testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'

        // log
        implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.36'

        // test
        testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:4.0.0'
        testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:4.0.0'
        testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
        testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

        // mapstruct
        compileOnly 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.5.2.Final'
        annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.5.2.Final'
        annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok-mapstruct-binding:0.2.0'
        testAnnotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.5.2.Final'
    }

    test {
        finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
        finalizedBy jacocoTestCoverageVerification
        useJUnitPlatform()
        testLogging.exceptionFormat = 'full'
        testLogging {
            events 'passed', 'skipped', 'failed'
        }

        jacocoTestReport {
            dependsOn test // tests are required to run before generating the report

            afterEvaluate {
                classDirectories.setFrom(files(classDirectories.files.collect {
                    fileTree(dir: it, exclude: [

                    ])
                }))
            }
        }
    }

    publishing {
        publications {
            mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
                groupId = project.group
                artifactId = project.name
                version = project.version
                from components.java
            }
        }
        repositories {
            maven {
                credentials {
                    username System.getenv('GIT_USER')
                    password System.getenv('GIT_PASSWORD')
                }
                url "${artifactoryRepo}"
            }
        }

    }

    javadoc {
        if (JavaVersion.current().isJava11Compatible()) {
            options.addBooleanOption('html5', true)
        }
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    }
}
```